# How to pass Collection of events in Esper EPL statement

Tags: events, esper

I have created a new single row function which takes collection of events as input parameter. I am able to to process single event parameters in EPL statement but not able to find out how to pass colection of events as parameter in EPL statement.

Suppose I have created a function named percent which takes event as only parameter  and it is getting processed using below EPL query:
    ***select * from MyEvent(percent(me)< 20) as me*** 
But if i create a function which takes collection of events as parameter i am unable to pass it.
    ***select * from Stock_Event_Rank(rank(me)) as me***

Here I want to pass me as collection of events. Will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In the scope of a filter there is no collection of events.
The only collection of events is when there is a data window.
For example:`select rank(window(*)) from StockEvent.win:length(10)`
This is so because the Esper doesn't keep just events, unless there is a data window and that means Esper does keep a certain subset of events. I also recommend looking at aggregation functions or plugin aggregation functions or the "ranked" data-window. This is so because "rank(window(*))" would probably need to recompute ranks for every event that comes and goes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood my mistake that I was doing by not defining the data window.